# I have a following code to refresh the div, not a whole html page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

After refreshing.....it goes on to the main page but not on the current page. What to do if it will be on the same page after refreshing. I have one index.html page but with 6 swiper slides...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function autoRefresh_div()
{
    $("#MyDIV").load("load.html");// a function which will load data from other file after x seconds
}
setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 5000); // refresh div after 5 secs
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe this article can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370417/how-to-load-external-html-into-a-div

Comment: try to remove "'" :  setInterval(autoRefresh_div, 5000); the first parameter is a function.

Comment: whats the error you get now?

Comment: After refreshing?? what, the page? this does not alter the html page file  ($("#MyDIV").load("load.html");) but the DOM in memory

Comment: its not an error....its refreshing but after refreshing it goes on the main page instead of current page.....there 6 swiper slides in one html page

Comment: empty the div 1st before you load ($("#MyDIV").empty();)

Comment: check your `load.html` page, may be the page has some content for that the page goes to `main page`. and remove the quota from `setInterval` and also the function sign.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would be helpful.
**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head> 
  <body>
    <div id="myDiv">Loading...</div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
      $("#myDiv").load("sample.html");
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

**Example**: http://plnkr.co/edit/jgIMZ9Y1l167VHFg32Ik?p=preview