# How to include HTML menu in separate file using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to include a HTML menu in a separate file using jQuery so I don't have to change all the pages every time I change something in menu. I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>$(".top-menu").load("menu.html");</script>

    </br>
    <div>
        Some text
        <audio autoplay><source src="some-sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The menu is in file "menu.html":

```
<nav class="top-menu">
    <ul class="menu-main">
        <li><a href="pageone.html">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="pagetwo.html">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="pagethree.html">Three</a></li>/
        <li><a href="pagefour.html">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

But the menu doesn't show up on this page. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load external html into a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370417/how-to-load-external-html-into-a-div)

Comment: @Jakub Raban, have we solved your problem ? Check green tick on the best answer if yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to make an element where you want to put your menu, for example:

```
<body>
    <div class="top-menu"></div>
    ...
</body>
```

Then put this at the end of your document, before closing `<body>` tag.

```
<script>$(".top-menu").load("menu.html");</script>
```

I would highly recommend you to use an MVC framework, where you can define layout and then single pages will be the views. That depends on you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `$(".top-menu")` if the element `<nav class="top-menu">` isn't in the same page.

Add a div with `id="menu"`, and try to full it, like :

```
<body>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    </br>
    <div>
        Some text
        <audio autoplay><source src="some-sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    </div>
    <script>$("#menu").load("menu.html");</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way. (In you main/index.html file)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#anyDiv').load('some-local-path/menu.html');
 });
```

`anyDiv` may be a `div` element in you `main.html` page where you're trying to include `menu.html`

Make sure that you've both of the files on the same domain, otherwise you'll have to use `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing`